# Generating AES key after ECDH

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I am using ECDH to have a shared secret between Alice and Bob one running on Android and the other on embedded. My understanding is that the best practice is that both sides generate an AES key to encrypt messages. Can someone send some example on how both sides Alice and Bob generate the same AES key after they have agreed on a shared secret by using ECDH?

Comment: You may only get hints on how to implement this, asking for code is usually voted as off topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably best to follow the NIST recommendations on Key Agreement schemes, e.g. using [NIST SP 800-56A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56A/SP800-56A_Revision1_Mar08-2007.pdf) with the [recommendations in the implementers guide](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/SuiteB_Implementer_G-113808.pdf) and one of the key derivation methods specified in [NIST SP 800-108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf). It describes how to convert the secret to bytes, and then one of the KDF's can be used to convert to (multiple) keys.

Note that the key derivations are in the lightweight API of Bouncy Castle since 1.50 and should therefore also be present in [Spongy Castle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/). The most common NIST algorithm is in `org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.KDFCounterBytesGenerator`. You can simply give it any  HMAC (say HMAC SHA1) in the constructor and `org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KDFCounterParameters` during initialization.

Note that this adheres to better cryptographic practices than the answer of Perseids, but may be significantly harder to understand/implement.

Comment: Can someone specify the API call? Is it PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1AndUTF8? What is the class/interface that implemented the API?

Comment: No that first PB means "Password Based". You need a KBKDF (Key Based) KDF as your shared secret already contains enough entropy.  I'll amend answer... I've actually created the initial implementation of them :)

Comment: Do you find the following code meeting the recommendations for KDF:
                    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(ecdh_shared_secret, salt, 65536, 256);
                    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
                    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

Comment: Nowadays you should also take note of HKDF. I'll try and update the answer later at home.

Comment: eventually I used the following function:
    public static SecretKey createAESKey(byte[] aSecret) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {     
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(aSecret, "AES");
        return secret;
    }

Comment: For that to work the secret must be exactly the correct size. It probably contains enough entropy to be safe, *but it may not be fully random*. That's why NIST requires a KDF to be deployed. I would recommend to at least hash the secret with e.g. SHA-512 and use the leftmost bytes as key instead.

Answer (score 3):

After the successful ECDH run you've got the same group element on both ends. You now need to define a uniform encoding of the elements as byte array / octet stream. Using a hash function (for example SHA256) you can reduce the array to a 256bit value. If you need to derive several keys you can append the byte array with different constants for every key before hashing them.

A simple example: Let's say your elliptic curve point is (51357992175,89175716892). You can represent that curve point as the string "(51357992175,89175716892)". For different keys you can append some string constants like "MacKey" or "EncryptionKey". To get some raw byte values you can encode these strings with utf8. Overall the keys would be:

```
macKey        = sha256("(51357992175,89175716892)MacKey".getBytes("UTF-8"))
encryptionKey = sha256("(51357992175,89175716892)EncryptionKey".getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

---

**Edit**, regarding your question arising from the comments ("In my case I have one server and many clients that approach to him several times a day, and need to have a different AES key each time based on the shared secret.") on how to produce a large number of keys, one for each communication event:

**You are getting into the - rather complex - area of cryptographic protocol design.** Think about these questions:

- How do you guarantee that a different key is generated for each new *sent* message? Standard solutions would be the use of a counter or a random number as nonce (number used once), each of them having their own problems. (Counter: It has to be strictly monotonic even in case of an application crash or backup restore. Random: It has to be large enough to prevent random collisions - something like 256bit would suffice - and you have to continuously trust the random number generator to be good.)
- How do you prevent message replays attacking the *receiving* side? You can keep track of every nonce used (storage intensive) or possibly use a monotonic counter in case the nonce is monotonic and reject any message having a nonce less or equal the monotonic counter.
- How do you react to message *delaying*, *reordering* or *selective* message *blocking*? In many cases it is important to be able to notice these events and you have to decide what to do in then. (TLS for example requires live interactions between the two parties and aborts the connection if anything arrives out of order, but is not able to detect delays (except if the now infamous heartbeats are used to ping the connection).)

**With the extended warning behind us, back to your question:** For each new key you can use a *nonce* (number used once) that is included in the key derivation to generate a unique key for the purpose. I'm basically rebuilding something similar to "5.1 KDF in Counter Mode" from [NIST SP 800-108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf), which owlstead has already mentioned, with plain text components. At this point I would recommend to read it in any way as it is not that long and contains a lot of background considerations. Additionally to the nonce you should narrow the use of the key as close as possible. For example on the server side use:

```
macKey = sha256(sha256("(51357992175,89175716892); MacKey; ServerToClient; 2755".getBytes("UTF-8")))
```

for the 2755th key generated for message authentication purposes for communication from the server to the client. You can see the following components: The shared secret (the elliptic curve point), the purpose of the key (mac), the communication direction, a counting nonce. Also I use double hashing here to prevent any kind of [length extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) on the hash; an HMAC would be just as good here. The nonce itself can, and has to in some case, be published alongside of the message. In itself it does not contain any sensitive information.

Comment: Rather simple, proprietary solution, but not incorrect or particularly insecure, so an upvote from me.

Comment: @owlstead You are right, it is rather an ad hoc approach (I've interpreted the question as only educational, otherwise the typical "don't implement your own crypto" advice applies). It'd be very interested, though, how the solution is any less secure than the NIST approaches (or which cryptographic best practices it violates).

Comment: It's unlikely that it is much less safe; all the information about the secret is included in the KDF. The makeshift KDF (which is rather like KDF0/KDF1 that uses a counter) has at least the theoretical issue that a hash function is not (designed to be) a PRF.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks :), I was thinking about asking such a question myself (after taking a closer look at the NIST documents when I had had the time).

Comment: Even for educational puprose (which is not the case :-) ) how would you make both sides Alice and Bob, add the same constants in order to get the same symmetric keys? They need now to agree on a mechanism to define the same constants.

Comment: @Simon: These constants should be chosen in the protocol definition and hard coded in the implementation. So similarly to the chosen generator of the group both sides do already know them. Re: educational or not - well, you have been warned :)

Comment: In my case I have one server and many clients that approach to him several times a day, and need to have a different AES key each time based on the shared secret. So "constant management" seems a little complex here. I will be glad to hear of a simple solution for that :-)