# Invalid AES key length: 128 bytes?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am getting `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 128 bytes` on my line

```
CIPHER.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
```

with CIPHER being

```
Cipher CIPHER = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

and keySpec

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

that key is a `byte[]` of length 128 I got through a Diffie-Hellman key exchange (though it shouldn't matter where I got it, right?), `key` is completely filled with nonzero bytes

Why is `Cipher.init(...)` complaining that the key is a wrong length? [This webpage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) clearly states that a key of length 128 is supported.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: I believe you want 128 bits key - not 128 bytes?

Comment: oops right herp derp. Please put this as an answer, so I can accept it and maybe a suggestion for what encryption algo to use with 128 bytes of key

Comment: Ok. Posting answer now

Comment: Hi vrwim, what algo did you end up using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need 128 bit key here for AES algorithm - not 128 byte. To convert your long key to needed length you could try something like password-based key derivation function. See PBKDF2 for example.

Comment: PBKDF2 is a bit of an overkill for high entropy material like Diffie-Hellman group elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167936/generating-aes-key-after-ecdh for more information on that @vrwim

Comment: I have read some up on PBKDF2, but that seems to be for password hashes, so they are more difficult to be cracked with rainbow tables. I have the security from my DH key exchange right? I think I just need a hashing function to hash the key to something that is the right length?

Comment: @vrwim Yes, that should be sufficient, check [this Q/A](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15673/security-of-kdf1-and-kdf2-hash-based-kdfs). KDF1 and 2 are not much more than hash outputs.

Answer (score 8):

AES algorithm allows 128, 192 or 256 bit key length. which is 16, 24 or 32 byte. your keys length should be 16 , 24 or 32 bytes.